# Sapply is turning a vector into a vector of vectors.. I think

Tags: r, apply, sapply

Honestly I am unsure if the title accurately describes what's happening, but here it goes.

Suppose I start with the following object "Tempcheck"

```
> str(Tempcheck)
'data.frame':   1872 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ Time           : POSIXlt, format: "2013-07-10 14:26:40" "2013-07-10 14:26:43" "2013-07-10 14:26:50" "2013-07-10 14:26:53" ...
 $ rawTemp        : int  107461 108551 109940 110258 110740 110890 111096 111164 111238 111296 ...
 $ rawConductivity: int  969903 1287631 1298627 1292063 1303909 1297249 1305610 1297557 1305070 1298703 ...
```

I then call a function and use sapply to normalize some data.

```
TCalibration<- function(x){                        #this function normalizes data based on the calculated y intercept and slope
  dc <- (x*((Tempcor[[2]])))+((Tempcor[[1]]))   # y = 1/m*x + -1/b
  dc <- dc[[1]]
}
##calibrates rawTemp into real temp
Tempcheck$Temp <- sapply(Tempcheck[[2]],TCalibration)
```

Tempcor is a previous object that stores coefficients from a linear model. If this is relevant I can post it later.

```
   > str(Tempcheck)
'data.frame':   1872 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ Time           : POSIXlt, format: "2013-07-10 14:26:40" ...
 $ rawTemp        : int  107461 108551 109940 110258 110740 110890 111096 111164 111238 111296 ...
 $ rawConductivity: int  969903 1287631 1298627 1292063 1303909 1297249 1305610 1297557 1305070 1298703 ...
 $ Temp           : num  23.6 23.9 24.3 24.4 24.5 ...
```

This is all fine and dandy! UNTIL ....

I call another function

```
 ConductivityCorrection <- function(x){
t <- 1+.02*(Tempcheck$Temp-25)  
EC25 <- (x/t) 
}
```

Then use sapply again to Tempcheck

```
Tempcheck$rawCEC <-sapply(Tempcheck[[3]] ,ConductivityCorrection)
```

I was expecting to get the same thing that I got with the previous line of code, but something strange happened.

```
   str(Tempcheck$rawCEC)

num [1:1872, 1:1872] 998390 991974 983917 982090 979335 ...
```

The length of this vector is 1872^2 which I thought was odd.  My suspision is that it comes from the line

```
t <- 1+.02*(Tempcheck$Temp-25)
```

I know i could do this a different way, but I'm trying to force my self to use the apply family and learn it better. Anyway any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

I am aware that this piece of code solves my problem.

```
    Tempcheck$alphaT <- 1+.02*(Tempcheck$Temp-25)
Tempcheck$rawCEC  <- Tempcheck[[3]]/Tempcheck$alphaT
```

I was looking for a way to turn this into a function and apply to each element in the column of Tempcheck[[3]]

Comment: Your function `CondictivityCorrection` doesn't explicitly return anything. In fact, I think you're confused with both of your functions about what (if anything) they are returning.

Comment: There isn't quite enough information here to grasp _exactly_ what your functions are supposed to do, but I'm almost certain that there's absolutely no need to apply functions here. I feel certain this should all be easily vectorized.

Comment: I know I can vectorize these operations, but I thought I'd challenge my self to figure out how to properly make and use functions. What would you suggest?

Comment: Sorry for the previous comment, got confused. I just can't really tell what those functions are supposed to be doing at all.

Comment: They are supposed to just apply the simple correction algorithm to each element in the array. In the case of the second function it looks at the corresponding temperature element to "x" normalizes it then that corrected value is used to correct the conductivity. I hope that answers you question, but I feel that it doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `Tempcheck$Temp` in your `ConductivityCorrection` function is a vector so `t` is a vector and thus `x/t` also returns a vector.  Instead you can use `mapply` or `sapply(seq_along(Tempcheck[[3]]), ...)` and index both accordingly.

```
ConductivityCorrection <- function(x){
  t <- 1+.02*(Tempcheck$Temp[x]-25)  
  EC25 <- (Tempcheck$rawConductivity[x]/t) 
}

sapply(seq_along(Tempcheck$Temp, ConductivityCorrection)
```

Generally, if you're `apply`ing a function to every row in a data.frame, you can vectorize your solution and skip `apply` functions altogether:

```
Temcheck$Temp <- Tempcheck$rawTemp * Tempcor[[2]] + Tempcor[[1]]

Tempcheck$rawCEC <- Tempcheck$rawConductivity / (1 + 0.02 * (Tempcheck$Temp - 25))
```

However, for simpler functions like these, I really like the `data.table` syntax:

```
DT <- data.table(Tempcheck)

DT[, rawCEC := rawConductivity / (1 + 0.02*Temp - 25)]`)
```

Comment: I didn't get a chance to play with the data.table package yet, but I will. The previous line of code worked great! Question though, how would I have ever thought to do something like this. I feel as if I am missing something in how I think/ go about creating functions. More over can you explain seq_along() a bit. Thank you for your help again!!

Comment: you can read the help of `seq_along`, but it makes a sequence similar to doing `1:length(x)`, but a little safer.  `R` and vectorized languages in general take a little getting used to if you're coming from one that isn't, but keep exploring and asking questions; you'll get there.